# How can you view the total sum from a list c#

Tags: c#, list, class

```
GloryDays.Add(new Songs("Shout Out to My Ex", 200));
GloryDays.Add(new Songs("Touch",              161));
GloryDays.Add(new Songs("Power",              177));
GloryDays.Add(new Songs("Your Love",          210));
GloryDays.Add(new Songs("Nobody Like You",    180));
GloryDays.Sum(S => S.TrackLength);
```

This is what I got so far but I cannot seem to find a way to output the data. This project has to classes `Albums` and `Songs` and in songs class it contains accessors for `TrackName` and `TrackLength`.

Comment: What data do you want to output?  Why isn't this doing what you need it to do?

Comment: You need to save the return value of Enumerable.Sum into a variable and do something with it.

Comment: Thanks for replies guys I want to input the total sum in textbox which represents the album length

Comment: @Mobster007 why did you remove the answer?

Comment: @Mobster007 may be the OP did not like your commanding tone in the comment below your answer, where you request the marking of your answer. Keyword: [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood)

Comment: you talking to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<Songs> GloryDays = new List<Songs>();
 GloryDays.Add(new Songs { TrackName = "Shout Out to My Ex", TrackLength =200 });
 GloryDays.Add(new Songs { TrackName = "Touch", TrackLength = 161 });
 var result = GloryDays.Sum(t => t.TrackLength);
 textbox1.Text = result.ToString();
```